# Why was the Handel Gothic BT typeface specified for use on signs by fire codes?

Tags: fonts

...so I've been noticing that all the Fire Department signs in the Phoenix, Arizona area seem to be the same "Star Trek TNG"-ish font, which I looked up and identified as Handel Gothic, and lo and behold, the [2018 International Fire Code as Amended by the City of Phoenix](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/PHXFC2018P1/appendix-d-fire-department-details) specifies that the signs are to be lettered in Handel Gothic BT capitals, white lettering on a red background.

This appears to be true for other cities as well, including
[Anaheim, CA](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/anaheim/latest/anaheim_ca/0-0-0-63238)
and [Atlanta, GA](http://atlanta.elaws.us/code/coor_ptii_ch78_artiii_sec78-57), and numerous others ([Woodburn, Oregon](https://woodburnfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/manual-0204105.pdf); [Allen, Texas](https://www.cityofallen.org/DocumentCenter/View/377/AFD-Sign-Specifications---July-2020); [Princeton, Texas](https://www.princetontx.gov/DocumentCenter/View/204/Fire-Safety-Sign-Requirements-PDF); [Frederick County, Maryland](https://frederickcountymd.gov/DocumentCenter/View/18517/Signage-Requirements)).

My question is: **why?**

It seems far less readable (especially the use of all caps) than [FHWA's Highway Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_Gothic) for road signs.

Comment: I'm afraid the **only** way this is answerable is to contact the city planners or councils. It was *their preference* to set that parameter.

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable.  Why anyone chooses a particular font is subjective. Whoever set up these standards must have liked that font. Perhaps they were a Star Trek fan?

Comment: It sounds like it may have come from the International Fire Code itself though (I don't have access to pay standards) --- I would have thought it was a Phoenix thing, but why is it all over the place? I can't imagine someone choosing a font for a standard just because they liked it; FHWA fonts were the result of significant research.